# Logging URL's from a txt file

Tags: python, parsing, logging

I want to add logging into my code but I am not sure how to do it. I have a txt file with 3 URLs in it and I have been retrieving information from it. I want to log the date and time, if the URL was successfully retrieved, and the customer ID.
Here is the code that I have:

```
import requests
import logging
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
with open ('h9-text', 'r') as f:
    h9 = f.readlines()
    for url in h9:
        url = url.strip()
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print("Attempting to retrieve data from:", r.url)
            print("200 - Successfully retrieved:", r.url)
            root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
            for customer in root.findall("customer"):
                name = customer.find('name').text
                checking_accounts = customer.findall('checking_account')
                savings_account = customer.findall('savings_account')
                for account in checking_accounts:
                    print(name, "Checking Account:", account.text)
                for accounts in savings_account:
                    print(name, "Savings Account:", accounts.text)
        elif r.status_code == 404:
            print("Attempting to retrieve data from:", r.url)
            print("Resource not found")
```

And here are the 3 URLs in the 'h9' text file:

```
http://kitty.ninja/file1.xml
http://kitty.ninja/badurl.xml
http://kitty.ninja/file3.xml
```

Comment: You are already printing stuff out, which is kind of like logging. What else do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am printing out the checking and savings accounts, but I would like to log the client ID's (this is all fictional, not real peoples accounts)

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3, you can use f-strings to interpolate results. You can add these to your inner loop to print out the customer ID for example.

```
id = customer.find('id').text
print(f"id {id}")
```

Comment: How would I create just a separate log for the client's ID? I know that it is not needed and kind of repetitive but I am wanting to learn how to implement logging into my code.